# R read.zoo() can's accept object's value input as an argument. R

Tags: r, parameter-passing, zoo

I created one data.frame called data1 and read it by read.zoo function as follows works perfectly.

```
data2<-read.zoo(data1)
```

now I do this for the whole list of existing data.frames by using following code .

```
names_of_dataframes <- ls.str(mode = "list")
data2<-read.zoo(name_of_dataframes[1])
```

This gives the following error.
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'data1': No such file or directory

Thought it's character string issue then tried the following but seems not working

```
data2<-read.zoo(as.character(name_of_dataframes[1]))
```

Now how can I pass the value of 'data1' to read.zoo? 
there are about 100 data and want to make it automated from the list of dataframes.

Thank you R Gurus,
Kaz

Comment: Please review [mcve] cutting your problem down to a smaller size that still shows the problem and is reprodudible.

Comment: `read.zoo` works the same as `read.table` in that if you give it a character string it will interpret it as a filename.  If `nm <- "DF"` and `DF` is a data frame then read.zoo can read it using `read.zoo(DF)`  or `read.zoo(get(nm))` plus, of course, any additional arguments that may be needed.

Comment: data2<-read.zoo(get(as.character(name_of_dataframes[1]))

Comment: 'code' data2<-read.zoo(get(as.character(name_of_dataframes[1]))) works perfectly. thanks!